# using switchMap with combineLatest?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component with a QueryList:

```
 @ViewChildren(MyComponent) children!:QueryList<MyComponent>;
```

Each of these child components have an observable property on them, `instance$`, and I have an ngAfterViewInit that does:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  combineLatest(
    this.children.toArray().map(component => component.instance$)
  ).pipe(
    first()
  ).subscribe((instances: any[]) => {
    this.instances = instances;
  });
}
```

This works great, but I was next trying to implement the ability to dynamically add child components.. So I needed to use the `QueryList.changes` observable...

So I added to that:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  ...

  this.children.changes.pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      const observables = this.children.toArray().map(component => component.instance$);
      return combineLatest(observables);
    }),
  ).subscribe((instances: any[]) => {
    this.instances = instances;
  });
}
```

But the subscription function never seems to get triggered...  Why is `combineLatest` not working in this case?

**UPDATE**

It appears that I can get it to work by instead doing:

```
    this.children.changes.subscribe((children) => {
      const instances: any[] = [];
      const fetchInstanceFor = async (child: any) => {
        const instance = await firstValueFrom(child.instance$);
        return instance;
      };
      children.forEach((child: any) => {
        instances.push(fetchInstanceFor(child));
      });
      this.instances = instances;
    });
```

But... that seems awfully awful.  Is there a better way?!

Comment: does `component.instance$` fire for all the components? or might some component don't emit anything? `combineLatest` will emit only when all it's child have emitted something first

Answer (score 0):

`QueryList.changes` doesn't emit the initial state, it only emits when it "changes" :-)

You can use the `startWith` operator to emit the initial state like this:

```
  this.children.changes.pipe(
    startWith(this.children),
    switchMap(() => {
      const observables = this.children.toArray().map(component => component.instance$);
      return combineLatest(observables);
    }),
  ).subscribe(...)
```

---

Since you aren't currently using the value of the query list, you could emit any value `startWith(undefined)`, or if you wanted, you could actually use the emitted value instead of `this.children` inside your `switchMap`:

```
  this.children.changes.pipe(
    startWith(this.children),
    switchMap(ql => {
      const observables = ql.toArray().map(component => component.instance$);
      return combineLatest(observables);
    }),
  ).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: ok, I realized the problem with my subscription not firing was because `instance$` was a `Subject` and combineLatest apparently wasn't completing when `instances$` had previously emitted...  Changing that to a`BehaviorSubject` appears to make it work...  Except with a BehaviorSubject I initially have undefined values before the `instance$` has had `.next` called on it...  Is there a way to filter out undefined values from combineLatest?

Comment: I know I can do `return combineLatest(observables).pipe(first((values: any[]) => values.indexOf(undefined) === -1))` but am wondering if there's a better way to handle situations where BehaviorSubjects are initially emitting `undefined` values?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're doing, but maybe try `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of `BehaviorSubject`. This will prevent the "default" emission that you don't want.